# running .net console applications programmatically

Tags: .net, process, execution

I have a .exe program (console app) written in .net.

1. I need to execute it
2. Provide inputs
3. Get the outputs as a string or preferably as stream.

Currently I'm using `System.Diagnostics` namespace and `Process` Class. 
But using `Diagnostic` namespace for this purpose dosent seem to be ok.

Is there any method by which I can do the same thing more efficiently?.
Like using reflection to find `Main()` method and then invoking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Process` class is exactly the right tool for doing what you want. Don't mind the name of the `Diagnostic` namespace - just use the `Process` class.

Comment: thankx. i also need to run this process in a seperate app domain. can that be done using this namespace?

Comment: First: Forget about the namespace! Then, please read this to understand what a namespace is and why it shouldn't matter to you at all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx#assenamesp_topic5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991735/how-to-start-a-console-application-inside-a-different-app-domain.. may b u can help me with this second question i hav just posted.. read the link.thankx for that

Answer (score 0):

Completely fine. System.Diagnostics is just a namespace.

If more info needed, you can [navigate to this project](https://github.com/stenly311/ProcessRunner) for motivation and see how to handle processes grammatically or this snippet from [VM found in here](https://github.com/stenly311/ProcessRunner/blob/master/ProcessRunner/ViewModels/ProcessViewModel.cs)

```
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FilePath)
                {
                    WorkingDirectory = RootFolderPath,
                    Arguments = StartingArguments,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };
                ConsoleProcess = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};

                ConsoleProcess.Start();
```